# No net access from cmd

Tags: windows-7, proxy, internet-connection

**tl/nr:**

I am behind a proxy. The proxy configuration comes with a pac file. The internet connection is working fine in browsers but not on cmd. How can I access internet from everywhere?

**Long:**

I am behind a pac-configurated proxy server. I managed to find the proxy address as well as the needed credentials in the pac file. With those information I was able to set up e.g. apm (via .apmrc) to retrieve packages or sourcetree to push and pull at github. Interestingly, I am also able to push and pull at github via cmd (using its own config).

But somehow I'm not able to ping or wget from cmd.

To boil it down, it seems like every program where I can set the proxy by hand works fine, every program, where I have to rely on windows proxy settings doesn't.

I already tried to set enviroment variables with

- set http_proxy=[proxy] (with and without credentials)
- setx http_proxy [proxy] (with and without credentials)
- netsh winhttp set proxy [proxy]
- cntlm

My best bet was cntlm so far. I was able to set up a working connection to the proxy. When I change my browsers proxy settings to the local cntlm-"proxy", I have internet access. But still no access via cmd.

While it is annoying to not have any ping, it really bothers me, I am not able to use e.g. atom packages with web access like gist-it.

**Edit 1:**

While setting environment variable http_proxy: is it necessary to include my domain with my username, and if so, how?

**Edit 2:**

@Big Chris:

- I am not sure about TMG, but I will try that. **Result:** No forefront server found.
- It is totally thinkable that ping requests are blocked, I used it as a common example but am aware of that fact. Therefore I also tried things like *wget* and the intended usecase *gist-access from atom*.

Let's put it that way: What I try is not really wanted here. ;-) I don't want to wake sleeping dogs in central IT with corrupting questions.

Comment: Is your proxy a Microsoft TMG appliance? You could install the TMG client on your box and see if that helps. It helps non-proxy-aware applications to traverse the proxy. Also: does your proxy/firewall block outbound ICMP/ping requests? Our work network has the same - we can't ping external domains from cmd.